# Error: oracledb@0.6.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild` while installing oracledb module

Tags: node.js, oracle, database-connection, node-gyp, node-oracledb

I am working on Windows 7. I have tried a number of solutions mentioned here and there, but nothing seems to work.
I am trying to install oracledb module using the command "npm install oracledb", but i get the following error:

```
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program    Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@0.6.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@0.6.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledbnpm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The detailed log says:

```
229 verbose stack Error: oracledb@0.6.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
229 verbose stack Exit status 1
229 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
229 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
229 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
229 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
229 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
229 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
230 verbose pkgid oracledb@0.6.0
```

Has anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. There was some problem with my python variable, which i had set to some other directory. Once the python variable was set, it threw some error with my Visual Studio, saying cannot find "stdio.h". I had to repair my Visual Studio Installation, as i believe there was some issues with C++ Core libraries.
Oracledb installed successfully after that. Such a relief!

Comment: Hi Can you let me know how did you fix the issue as I am also facing the same issue