# npm error code ELIFECYCLE while installing node-oracledb on a windows System

Tags: node.js, npm, node-oracledb

Hi I am trying to install the [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin) on my windows system for my project. I have followed the exact process mentioned in the given [link](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin) and also used the given [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I23XTkUMrtM) to install the same. When I run `npm install oracle-db` I get the following error

```
    465 verbose stack Error: oracledb@1.12.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    465 verbose stack Exit status 1
    465 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\theon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
    465 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    465 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    465 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\theon\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
    465 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    465 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    465 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    465 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
    466 verbose pkgid oracledb@1.12.2
    467 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
    468 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    469 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\theon\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb"
    470 error node v6.9.4
    471 error npm  v4.1.1
    472 error code ELIFECYCLE
    473 error oracledb@1.12.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    473 error Exit status 1
    474 error Failed at the oracledb@1.12.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
    474 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    474 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
    474 error not with npm itself.
    474 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    474 error     node-gyp rebuild
    474 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    474 error     npm bugs oracledb
    474 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    474 error     npm owner ls oracledb
    474 error There is likely additional logging output above.
    475 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My `node` version is `v6.9.4` and `npm` version is `v4.1.1`. Also I am using python version `2.7` along with `visual studio 12`.

There are already two question related to this issues for which no revelant answers is being provided on stackoverflow. The questions are as follows

1. [Error while installing node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037671/error-while-installing-node-oracledb)
2. [Error: oracledb@0.6.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild` while installing oracledb module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724867/error-oracledb0-6-0-install-node-gyp-rebuild-while-installing-oracledb-modu)

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: There are similar questions with answers in the node-oracledb discussion on GitHub.

Comment: I looked those questions and tried those too but could not get it installed on windows. But I could easily install it on my mac and linux system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while installing node-oracledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037671/error-while-installing-node-oracledb)

Comment: This would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037671/error-while-installing-node-oracledb/44182915#44182915